# How can I prove the following equation for the angle between two vectors?

Tags: geometry, numerical-methods, vectors, analytic-geometry

I'm new in the Mathematics forum, I hope such questions are accepted. This is a problem I had to solve in a job interview, I still can't find the answer, which I guess it's pretty basic.

Given two vectors $x,y$, prove that the angle between them can be calculated as:

$$\theta = 2\arctan\left(\frac{\Big| |x| y- |y| x\Big|}{\Big| |x| y+ |y|x\Big|}\right)$$

I already tried writing $x$ and $y$ as vectors in the complex plane, I tried some graphical "methods" and using various trigonometric identities, but nothing got me close to an equation similar to that.

A second question asked what numerical advantages does this formula give with respect to the usual $\theta=\arccos\left(\frac{{x}\cdot{y}}{|x||y|}\right)$. I thought that $\arctan$ can accept any input, while $\arccos$ limits them in $[-1,1]$, but this doesn't sound like a numerical matter. Moreover, I see a subtraction in the first equation, which I guess might lead to some loss of significance problems. Is the first equation really numerically superior than the second one?

Comment: I have seen a few other posts where a job interviewer asked a mathematics textbook problem like this. May I ask what positions have interviews like this? I realize my question doesn't help you solve this problem; I am just curious.

Comment: I had to really grit my teeth and concentrate just to be sure I was parsing all those bars correctly. Surely we can do better with regards to notation there!

Comment: @JohnDouma The position is flight dynamics engineer

Comment: Consider that $\arccos x$ has vertical asymptotes at $x=\pm 1$. In other words, it is very sensitive to change there, so the formula will be prone to error when the two vectors are aligned. For example, in Desmos, if I use ${\bf x} = {\bf y} = [1, 1]$, then the $\arccos$ formula gives $\theta = 2.1073 \times 10^{-8}$, whereas the $\arctan$ formula gives the correct answer, $\theta = 0$.

Comment: Demo showing the behaviour around ${\bf x} = [1, 1], {\bf y} = [1 + \epsilon, 1]$: https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ezuxfutyqs. The chunky purple line shows the problem with $\arccos$; the blue line shows the correct graph using $\arctan$.

Comment: One last follow-up: you observed that $\arccos$ limits the input to $[−1,1]$, but "this doesn't sound like a numerical matter." On the contrary, it is a grave numerical matter. In my earlier comment, with ${\bf x} = {\bf y} = [1,1]$, floating point error in the denominator gives $\sqrt 2 \cdot \sqrt 2 = 2 + \epsilon$ for some tiny $\epsilon > 0$. This is bad enough. But if the error had gone the other way, i.e., if the denominator had been $2 - \epsilon$, then we could not have taken $\arccos$ at all! Indeed, for ${\bf x} = {\bf y} = [3,3]$, for example, Desmos gives "undefined".

Comment: The edit by Marc seems misleading, the $\cdot$ makes it look like this is dot products.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\|x\|$y and $\|y\|x$ are two vectors with the same length.

Geometrically they would form two sides of a rhombus, where one diagonal length is the length of $\|x\|y+\|y\|x$ as from the parallelogram addition rule, and the other diagonal length is the length of $\|x\|y-\|y\|x$.

[image]

The two diagonals intersect at their midpoints at a right angle. Diagonals bisect rhombus corners. Consider one of the four right angles in the rhombus,

$$\tan\frac\theta2 = \cfrac{\left\|\cfrac{\|x\|y-\|y\|x}{2}\right\|}{\left\|\cfrac{\|x\|y+\|y\|x}{2}\right\|}$$

---

For question 2, my guess would be related to rounding error when $\theta$ is small? Then $\cos \theta$ would be close to $1$, and inverting $\cos$ precisely would require more significant figures.

Inspired by the comment in the [spherical law of cosines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_law_of_cosines) about rounding errors and the alternative formulation of the law of haversines.

Answer (score 3):

We can assume wlog, by homogeneity, that $|x|=|y|=1$, then by a simple geometric construction we obtain that

$$\frac{| |x|y- |y|x|}{| |x|y+ |y|x|} = \frac{| y- x|}{| y+ x|} =\frac{2\sin \frac \theta 2}{2\sin \left(\frac{\pi -\theta}2\right)}=\frac{\sin \frac \theta 2}{\cos \frac \theta 2}=\tan \frac \theta 2$$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you divide top and bottom by $|x||y|$ the expression becomes
$$\theta = 2\arctan\left(\frac{|\hat y- \hat x|}{|\hat y +\hat x|}\right)$$
where $\hat x$ indicates the unit vector in the $x$ direction. Then the length of the vector $\hat y+\hat x$ is $|\hat y+\hat x|=2\cos(\theta/2)$ and the length of the vector $\hat y-\hat x$ is $|\hat y-\hat x|=2\cos(90-\theta/2)=2\sin(\theta/2)$.

I've left explanation of the geometry to the following crudely-drawn figure. Note that $(\hat x+\hat y )\cdot(\hat x-\hat y)=0$, so the two lines are perpendicular. Another way to see that is to view $2\hat x$ as a diameter and $\hat y$ as the radius of a circle, then the angle between these becomes the inscribed angle of a diameter, which is a right angle.

[image: Picture of unit vectors and angles]

I don't have an answer for the second part of your question, something to do with numerical stability for relatively small or large values?